# Invertible operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We consider the operator $$T=I + {{{\partial ^2}} \over {\partial {x^2}}}:{H^2}(0,L) \cap H_0^1(0,L) \to {L^2}(0,L)$$
We hope to prove that $T$ is invertible if and only if  $L = n\pi $.
and for this purpose we must show that $T$ is injective and surjective. For
$T$ is Injective:
$${\rm{Ker\{ T\}  = \{  u}} \in {H^2}(0,L) \cap H_0^1(0,L),\sin(L) = 0\}  = \{ 0\} $$  implies $L = n\pi $.
For $T$ is surjective:
the solution can be calculated explicitly for all $f$ in  ${L^2}(0,L)$.

My question is: How can we prove the only if statement.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't you have this reversed?  $u = \sin(x)$ satisfies $u + u''  = 0$, and so if this is in your domain the operator is **not** invertible.

Comment: What about boundary conditions ?

Comment: What about changing variables $t = x/L$ to convert the problem to the interval $(0,1)$ and now you are looking at eigenvalues of $D=\partial^2/\partial t^2$? Your only if statement seems to be equivalent to the statement about eigenvalues of $D$. I'm no expert in this, so just an idea.

Comment: Thanks....the equation becomes:$$Tu = \sum\limits_{n > 0} {{u_n}(1 - {{({{n\pi } \over L})}^2})\sin (} {{n\pi } \over L}x)$$ but i'm blocked here.